# Get ConfigurationElement parent in app.config

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationsection, configurationelement

I have created a custom `ConfigurationSection`, `ConfigurationElement(s)` and `ConfigurationElementCollection(s)` for my *app.config*, it's based on [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx).

Now I would like to be able to access a parent element in any configuration element.
For example something in the lines of the following:

```
public class CustomSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("child")]
    public ChildElement Child
    {
        get { return (ChildElement)this["child"]; }
        set { this["child"] = value; }
    }
}

public class ChildElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("nestedchild")]
    public NestedChildElement NestedChild
    {
        get { return (NestedChildElement)this["nestedchild"]; }
        set { this["nestedchild"] = value; }
    }
}

public class NestedChildElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    public void Sample()
    {
        // How can I access parent ChildElement object
        // and also its parent CustomSection object from here?
    }
}
```

Is there something in the base `ConfigurationElement` class that I'm missing and that would enable me to do this?

I'm hoping if it's possible to achieve this with some kind of generic solution;
One that would not require to introduce something like a `Parent` property on each element and then need to assign that property value in each `ConfigurationProperty` getter.

Comment: "ChildElement" class is not parent class of "NestedChildElement" classs.

Comment: Notice that the "ChildElement" contains a "ConfigurationProperty" or "NestedChildElement". In "app.config" this is a "nestedchild" XML element that is the parent of "child" XML element. I hope this explains things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't missed anything in `ConfigurationElement`, it's unable to give you any hierarchy or order information. You'll have to keep this information yourself, for example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044871/how-do-i-use-net-custom-configurationelement-properties-on-descendent-elements#7053238).

For a generic solution you may want to check out [my POC](https://github.com/MarioZ/ConfigPoc) for defining parent placeholders in app.config.
As a side note, in previous version I've done this with interface (you could check previous commits) and in the current version with extension property.

Also, the following is a trimmed down version that accomplishes just your requirement:

```
public abstract class ConfigurationElementBase : ConfigurationElement
{
    protected T GetElement<T>(string name) where T : ConfigurationElement
        => this.GetChild<T>(name);
}

public abstract class ConfigurationSectionBase : ConfigurationSection
{
    protected T GetElement<T>(string name) where T : ConfigurationElement
        => this.GetChild<T>(name);
}

public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<ConfigurationElement, ConfigurationElement> Parents =
        new Dictionary<ConfigurationElement, ConfigurationElement>();

    public static T GetParent<T>(this ConfigurationElement element) where T : ConfigurationElement
        => (T)Parents[element];

    private static void SetParent(this ConfigurationElement element, ConfigurationElement parent)
        => Parents.Add(element, parent);

    private static object GetValue(this ConfigurationElement element, string name)
        => element.ElementInformation.Properties.Cast<PropertyInformation>().First(p => p.Name == name).Value;

    internal static T GetChild<T>(this ConfigurationElement element, string name) where T : ConfigurationElement
    {
        T childElement = (T)element.GetValue(name);
        if (!Parents.ContainsKey(childElement))
            childElement.SetParent(element);
        return childElement;
    }
}
```

Now you can use these base configuration classes in your custom section as following:

```
public class CustomSection : ConfigurationSectionBase
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("child")]
    public ChildElement Child => base.GetElement<ChildElement>("child");
}

public class ChildElement : ConfigurationElementBase
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("nestedchild")]
    public NestedChildElement NestedChild => base.GetElement<NestedChildElement>("nestedchild");
}

public class NestedChildElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    public void Sample()
    {
        ChildElement parentChildElement = this.GetParent<ChildElement>();
        CustomSection parentCustomSection = parentChildElement.GetParent<CustomSection>();
        // TODO Use the parents ...
    }
```